# OnCancel getting called immediately after onvalidatemerchant

Tags: applepay, applepayjs

I'm trying to set up a POC for applepay processing on the web. I have a site on Azure that is a verified merchant domain, and am able to generate payment sessions that look valid as far as I can tell, e.g.

```
{
    "epochTimestamp": 1618320255698,
    "expiresAt": 1618323855698,
    "merchantSessionIdentifier": "some identifier",
    "nonce": "some nonce",
    "merchantIdentifier": "some identifier",
    "domainName": "myVerifiedDomain.azurewebsites.net",
    "signature": "a nice long signature",
    "operationalAnalyticsIdentifier": "display name:the merchant session identifier above",
    "retries": 0
}
```

This is generated in the `onvalidatemerchant` event handler, and passed into `session.completeMerchantValidation`.

Using a sandbox account or a live Apple account with linked cards, the next thing that happens is an immediate "payment not completed" message in the ApplePay popup on the page, and the `oncancel` event is hit Inspecting the event, I don't see anything that hints at the issue. There is a `sessionError` object, but its code is `"unknown"` and the `info` object is empty.

What could be causing this? Other reports I've found seem to be mostly about the domain being unverified, but it definitely matches what is verified, and I've tried a few variations (including the https://, and the full page URL rather than just the domain) and I get the same symptoms

Comment: Similar wuestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55072781/apple-pay-completemerchantvalidation-cancels-session?rq=1 but the only answer there is about the domain being verified, which I'm fairly sure isn't the issue here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. The displayName property was missing in my model so wasn't being deserialised from the JSON

Answer (score 0):

Problem we ran into is that we weren’t rounding to 2 decimal points. Apple Pay wasn’t happy with `4.435` instead wants `4.44` for the amount.